# StreamReader.ReadLine() very strange behaviour

Tags: c#, stream

I have a delimited file with a few thousand lines in it, and I wrote a method to automatically detect the delimiter.

The method looks like this:

```
private bool TryDetermineDelimiter(FileInfo target, out char delimiter)
        {
            char[] possibleDelimiters = new char[] { ',', ';', '-', ':' };

            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(target.OpenRead()))
            {
                List<int> delimiterHits = new List<int>();

                foreach (char del in possibleDelimiters)
                {


                    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        var line = sr.ReadLine();
                        var matches = Regex.Matches(line, $"{del}(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)");

                        if(matches.Count == 0)
                        {
                            sr.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                            break;
                        }

                        delimiterHits.Add(matches.Count);
                    }

                    if (delimiterHits.Any(d => d != delimiterHits[0]) || delimiterHits.Count == 0)
                    {
                        delimiterHits.Clear();
                        continue;
                    }

                    delimiter = del;
                    return true;
                }
            }

            delimiter = ',';
            return false;
        }
```

There is a strange thing happening, where at the 5th line, the call to `sr.ReadLine()` is returning the 5th line *with the 1st line concatenated*

So for example:

delimited file:

```
col1; col2; col3; col4
val1; val2; val3; val4
val5; val6; val7; val8
...
```

The first 4 calls to `StreamReader.ReadLine()` return the expected lines **but** the 5th call returns: `val13; val14; val15; val16; col1; col2; col3; col4;`

Stepping through, I can confirm that the loop never enters the `if(matches.Count == 0)` block, the correct number of delimiters is found each iteration.

Unfortunately I can't post the contents of the *actual* file because it may get me in trouble, but I *have* ensured there is no fishy business with the line endings or other characters. The file is as expected.

I should also mention that this bug does not occur with *comma* separated values, only with *semicolons*.

Comment: When stepping through your code... at `var line = sr.ReadLine()`, is the `line` variable containing the value of 5th + 1st line concatenated?

Comment: It is likely that by the time you post an [MCVE] that includes a test data set that manifests the issue, you will have found the source of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to this

```
if (matches.Count == 0)
{
    sr.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    sr.DiscardBufferedData();
    break;
}
```

By instructing the `StreamReader` to discard its buffer, you're instructing it to synchronize with the actual base stream.

Other than that, the lines returned aren't concatenated, but it is looping back on its self, though what I've shown above will fix that